Error while compiling Godot for ARM64 from source
I tried to compile Godot from source. But it is throwing an error.
I followed this tutorial:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/contributing/development/compiling/compiling_for_linuxbsd.html#doc-compiling-for-linuxbsd
Command:
scons platform=linuxbsd

Error:
{standard input}: Assembler messages:                   
{standard input}:158598: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted                            
{standard input}:159807: Error: operand 2 must be an integer or stack pointer register -- `add x1,x'            
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive                            
g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus                                                      
compilation terminated.
scons: ***[modules/text_server_adv/text_server_adv.linuxbsd.editor.arm64.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.           
[Time elapsed: 00:46:11.081]


This is out of my knowledge. But you might try opening an issue at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues. You could also try to contact the developers at https://chat.godotengine.org/home in particular if you are modifying the source.
